# How to set default font for whole React-Native application

Tags: react-native, fonts, font-family

I would like to set any  tag font-family as a default font which i want. So if i want some component has another font i set them as style which is not too much.
What is the best way to not set every components separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to use consistent fonts and sizes across your application is to create a component `MyAppText` that includes them and use this component across your app.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text